# .GoogleAuthException: Unknown while doing Google SSO.

Tags: android, google-oauth, google-sso

Exception:

```
07-28 14:36:13.140: W/System.err(11382): com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
07-28 14:36:13.140: W/System.err(11382):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
07-28 14:36:13.140: W/System.err(11382):    at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
07-28 14:36:13.148: E/AndroidRuntime(11382): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

My Sign Up code:

```
public class Signup extends Activity {

      final private String CLIENT_ID = <android-client-id>;
      final private List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{
          "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"
      });
      private String webId = <web-client-id>;


      private GoogleAccountCredential mCredential;

      private EditText mExchangeCodeEditText;
      private EditText mIdTokenEditText;

      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_google);
        //mExchangeCodeEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextExchangeCode);
       // mIdTokenEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextIdToken);

        // initiate a credential object with drive and plus.login scopes
        // cross identity is only available for tokens retrieved with plus.login
        mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(this, Arrays.asList(SCOPES.get(0)));

        // user needs to select an account, start account picker
        startActivityForResult(
            mCredential.newChooseAccountIntent(), REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER);
      }

      /**
       * Handles the callbacks from result returning
       * account picker and permission requester activities.
       */
      @Override
      protected void onActivityResult(
          final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        switch (requestCode) {
        // user has  returned back from the account picker,
        // initiate the rest of the flow with the account he/she has chosen.
        case REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER:
          String accountName = data.getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
          if (accountName != null) {
            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(accountName);  
            new RetrieveExchangeCodeAsyncTask().execute();
            new RetrieveJwtAsyncTask().execute();
          }
          break;
        // user has returned back from the permissions screen,
        // if he/she has given enough permissions, retry the the request.
        case REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION:
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            // replay the same operations
            new RetrieveExchangeCodeAsyncTask().execute();
            new RetrieveJwtAsyncTask().execute();
          }
          break;
        }
      }

      /**
       * Retrieves the exchange code to be sent to the
       * server-side component of the app.
       */
      public class RetrieveExchangeCodeAsyncTask
          extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

          String scope = String.format("oauth2:server:client_id:%s:api_scope:%s",
              CLIENT_ID, TextUtils.join(" ", SCOPES));
          try {

              GoogleAccountCredential.usingAudience(Signup.this,   "server:client_id:" + webId);
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(

                Signup.this, mCredential.getSelectedAccountName(), scope);
          } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // TODO: handle the exception
          }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String code) {
          // exchange code with server-side to retrieve an additional 
          // access token on the server-side.
         // mExchangeCodeEditText.setText(code);
            Log.d("code",code);
        }
      }

      /**
       * Retrieves a JWT to identify the user without the
       * regular client-side authorization flow. The jwt payload needs to be
       * sent to the server-side component.
       */
      public class RetrieveJwtAsyncTask
          extends AsyncTask<Void, Boolean, String> {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
          String scope = "audience:server:client_id:" + CLIENT_ID;
          try {
            return GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(
                    Signup.this, mCredential.getSelectedAccountName(), scope);
          } catch(UserRecoverableAuthIOException e) {
            startActivityForResult(e.getIntent(), REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION);
          } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); // TODO: handle the exception
          }
          return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String idToken) {
          // exchange encrypted idToken with server-side to identify the user
         // mIdTokenEditText.setText(idToken);
            Log.d("idtoken",idToken);
        }
      }

      private static final int REQUEST_ACCOUNT_PICKER = 100;
      private static final int REQUEST_AUTHORIZATION = 200;

    }
```

I'm completely clueless what's happening here. Help?

Comment: Since when did the GoogleAuthUtil.getToken() method start throwing a GoogleAuthException with message "BadUsername" for an email that is not registered on a device, instead of the previous exception IllegalArgumentException with message "Non existing account 'email_address'" ?  
http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthUtil.html#getToken(android.content.Context , java.lang.String, java.lang.String)

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problem. In my case the problem was in missed application name in google console.

Open [console](https://console.developers.google.com) navigate to your project and choose "Consent screen". Fill in the "PRODUCT NAME" field and save.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to CheatEx, I had to select my email address from the "Consent Screen" page and save.