# GoogleAuthException Unknown Source

Tags: android, google-oauth, unknown-host

I am generating token using GoogleUtilAuth.getToken().I have also generated two client ids one for webpage and one for android application and both are in same project .Followed this link

[verification from back end server](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/01/verifying-back-end-calls-from-android.html)

here is my code :

```
package com.example.tokengenerate;

import java.io.IOException;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.Scopes;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    String scope="audience:server:client_id:CLIENTID OF WEBPAGE";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.printId);
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
        String id=null;
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            tv.setText(id);
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                String[] account=getAccountNames();
                for(int i =0;i<account.length;i++)
                {
                    try {
                    Log.e("account name", account[i]);
                     id=GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, account[i], scope);
                        Log.e("google id",id);
                    } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }



            return null;
        }
    }.execute(null,null,null);


    }
    private String[] getAccountNames() {
      AccountManager  mAccountManager = AccountManager.get(this);
        Account[] accounts = mAccountManager.getAccountsByType(
                GoogleAuthUtil.GOOGLE_ACCOUNT_TYPE);
        String[] names = new String[accounts.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            names[i] = accounts[i].name;
        }
        return names;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

Here is my Logcat:

```
08-27 19:19:54.641: W/System.err(9792): com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
08-27 19:19:54.651: W/System.err(9792):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
08-27 19:19:54.651: W/System.err(9792):     at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
08-27 19:19:54.651: W/System.err(9792):     at com.example.tokengenerate.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:45)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at com.example.tokengenerate.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:264)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-27 19:19:54.661: W/System.err(9792):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:864)
```

Totally stuck please help.Not getting where I am going wrong

Comment: Could we see the output from Log.e("account name")?  On first glance, your code looks reasonable

Comment: @TimBray Thank you sir for replying.In account name it is showing emial Id eg "xyz@gmail.com" also  it is giving this error only when I put scope=audience:server:client_id:CLIENTID OF WEBPAGE.But if I put scope = https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus then I got the token.

Comment: You might try adding `oauth2:` prefix to the scope.

Comment: @Bansal_Sneha, did u get it working? I am too stuck with oauth. What did u do to get it working?

Comment: @Gopinath I just used sample demo from sdk named auth and it is working fine

Comment: My app has been running just fine during development but as soon as I try a release APK then I get this same error.  I think it has to do with the signing key not matching the SHA1 fingerprint entered in the APIs & Auth / Credentials page of the App-Engine project.  However, I don't see any way to enter two fingerprints for the same app/clientid.

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25766367/599628

Answer (score 0):

Use this code to get the scope

```
String scope = "oauth2:" + Scopes.PROFILE;
```

and use this scpe here

```
id=GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(MainActivity.this, account[i], scope);
```

Then you can get your access tocken in variable "id".Simple method.