# How to use Google Drive on android?

Tags: android, google-drive-api

I connected google drive in the past.
but after I had update latest version of android sdk and google-play-service, I can't connect to google drive.

so I had to go along with guide document. (https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android)
but it is also not connected.

I obtain exception in two case.

```
com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
at com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(Unknown Source)
```

I check sha1 of keystore and package name.
I don't known why it is happen. help me! please!

**list of similar questions**
[1] [cannot upload to google drive from my android app com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException: Unknown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913363/cannot-upload-to-google-drive-from-my-android-app-com-google-android-gms-auth-go)
[2] [GoogleAuthException when obtaining an access token with ClientID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14407548/googleauthexception-when-obtaining-an-access-token-with-clientid)
[3] [GoogleAuthException: Unknown (android)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19071441/googleauthexception-unknown-android)

Answer (score 0):

The information at 
https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android
is out of date.

You should refer to these two questions for updated instructions

[usingOAuth2 deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17429798/usingoauth2-deprecated)

[LogCat message: The Google Play services resources were not found. Check your project configuration to ensure that the resources are included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18068627/logcat-message-the-google-play-services-resources-were-not-found-check-your-pr)

Comment: thank you for reply.
but I don't solve this problem.

I already added GooglePlayService project into eclipse.
also I added this project in Property-Android-Library.

for GooglePlayService start, I called GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable() after app is started.

I don't know why this situation occurred.