# unknown GoogleAuthException while getting the token

Tags: android, android-internet

Similar questions are already available. But in my case I checked both SHA1 and my scope, they are correct and the account is also available. But still it returns unknown GoogleAuthException.  My code is :-

MainActivity.java

```
package com.simon.learn.accountgetter;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.accounts.Account;
import android.accounts.AccountManager;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.GoogleAuthUtil;
import com.google.android.gms.auth.UserRecoverableAuthException;
import com.google.android.gms.common.AccountPicker;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    AccountManager am;
    Account[] accounts;
    ArrayList<String> accNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    Button signin;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        am = AccountManager.get(getApplicationContext());
        accounts = am.getAccountsByType("com.google");
        // accounts=am.getAccounts();
        signin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signinBt);
        signin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = AccountPicker.newChooseAccountIntent(null,
                        null, new String[] { "com.google" }, false, null, null,
                        null, null);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 13);

            }
        });
    }

    private void getToken(String accountName) {
        new GetTokenTask(MainActivity.this, accountName,
                "oauth2:https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile")
                .execute();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String token = null;
        if (requestCode == 13) {
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String accountName = data
                        .getStringExtra(AccountManager.KEY_ACCOUNT_NAME);
                Log.e("simon", accountName);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), accountName,
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                getToken(accountName);

                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                // "The token is : "+token, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
    }

    public class GetTokenTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {
        Activity activity;
        String scope;
        String email;

        public GetTokenTask(Activity activity, String email, String scope) {
            this.activity = activity;
            this.scope = scope;
            this.email = email;

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
            String token = null;
            try {
                Log.e("simon","Scope : "+scope+ " email "+ email);
                token = GoogleAuthUtil.getToken(activity, email, scope);
            } catch (UserRecoverableAuthException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("simon","UserRecoverableAuthException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("simon","IOException");
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (GoogleAuthException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("simon","GoogleAuthException : "+e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return token;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Log.e("simon", "The Token is : " + result);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Token is : " + result,
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }
    }
}
```

It is showing unknown GoogleAuthException. See my manifest file also

Manifest.java

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.simon.learn.accountgetter"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me. Thanks in advance

Comment: Check my solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25766367/599628

Comment: debug uses another sha1 certificate then the keystore ofcourse.. so you need to make another client ID for debug only! (https://console.developers.google.com/  -> api credentials)